# query data in database which expire in 2 days

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What i need here is that there is a expiry date in database, so I have to get all the records that expire in two days.

what I've done so far

```
 $returndata = $this->issueDB->where('return_date', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)')->get();
 return view('backend.return.index',['return', $returndata]);
```

Any help will be appreciated

**Edit**

Result is empty set of data, since there are data in database which are 2 days after current day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check the exact date, do this:

```
Model::whereDate('return_date', Carbon::today()->addDays(2)->toDateString())->get();
```

Comment: This did the trick `Carbon::today()->addDays(2)->toDateString()` thanks.